# Equality involving distribution functions

Tags: integration, proof-explanation

Let $F$ be a distribution function, and define $a(t) = \frac{1-F(t)}{\int^\infty_t \frac{1-F(x)}{x}dx}$.

How do we prove $-\log \int^\infty_t \frac{1-F(x)}{x} dx + \log \int^\infty_1 \frac{1-F(x)}{x}dx = \int^t_1 \frac{a(x)}{x}dx$?

For context, the line is stated in my textbook, and I have no idea how to see the equality:

[image]

*de Haan, Laurens; Ferreira, Ana*, Extreme value theory. An introduction., Springer Series in Operations Research and Financial Engineering. New York, NY: Springer (ISBN 0-387-23946-4/hbk). xvi, 417 p. (2006). [ZBL1101.62002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1101.62002).

Comment: Hint: $$
\frac{a(u)}{u}=\frac{\frac{1-F(u)}{u}}{\int_u^\infty\frac{1-F(x)}{x}\,dx}=-\frac{G'(u)}{G(u)}=-\frac{d}{du}\log G(u)\,.
$$ Now integrate both sides.

Comment: Very nice @KurtG.